# tf 2.0 AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'get_default_session'

Tags: keras, callback, conv-neural-network, mnist, tensorflow2.0

I am converting my mnist cnn ML code to tf 2.0. codes were running well in tf 1.13

After switch to tf 2.0 and modified it, at the step of model fitting, an error occurred.

code

```
annealer = LearningRateScheduler(lambda x: 1e-3 * 0.95 ** x)
batch_size = 100
epochs = 30
history = model.fit_generator(datagen.flow(X_train,Y_train, batch_size=batch_size),
                              epochs = epochs, 
                              validation_data = (X_val,Y_val),
                              verbose = 1, 
                              steps_per_epoch=X_train.shape[0] // batch_size,
                              callbacks=[annealer])
```

error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-39-d1e7a6160362> in <module>()
      7                               verbose = 1,
      8                               steps_per_epoch=X_train.shape[0] // batch_size,
----> 9                               callbacks=[annealer])  

5 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py in get_session()
    188     global _SESSION
    189 
--> 190     default_session = tf.get_default_session()
    191 
    192     if default_session is not None:

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'get_default_session'
```

if I remove 'callback' or switch model.fit without callbacks option, everything runs well.

and I assume this is some incompatibility issue.

any suggestion how to implement callback right, so that I can do the variable lr?

thanks.

Comment: which version of Keras are you using?

Comment: it's the tf 2.0 version, tf.keras.   2.2.4-tf

Comment: No, that's not the tf 2.0 version, the traceback you provided points to code outside of tensorflow

Comment: good point! i didn't import the  LearningRateScheduler from the tf.keras.callback which is something i missed. thank you man.